# Heroku can't find ffmpeg install included in NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run a ffmpeg command with the ffmpeg node package and it's working fine locally, giving me exit code 0 + the file, but when I publish the same code to Heroku it gives me error code 127 and does nothing.
This is the code I'm running, what could be wrong? The files/ and ffmpeg/ directory is in the project root, but only files/ gets found on Heroku while both gets found locally.

```js
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var pathToFfmpeg = ".\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg"

var ffmpeg = spawn(pathToFfmpeg,
        `-i ./files/noaudio.mp4 -i ./files/music.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac ./editedfiles/output.mp4`.split(" "),
        { shell: true })

    ffmpeg.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        console.log("ffmpeg shutdown: code " + code + ", signal " + signal)
    })
```

Comment: Could you post the error log with it as well? Could very well be that you used backslashes in your path instead of forward ones.

Comment: heroku uses linux type of system to run server.your path is using windows type \\
Try changing path with /.

Comment: @W3D3 The only error I get is "ffmpeg shutdown: code 127, signal null", the code is mostly copied from online so I'm not quite sure how to get more information. Changing the slashes to / gives me the same error

Comment: i don't know exactly how your files are copied to heroku but make sure your ffpeg binary is indeed marked executable, for example by running ```chmod +x ./ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg```
Code 127 is returned by your shell if either the executable does not exist or is not executable.

Comment: Heroku deploys the app automatically from my connected github repo. I tried moving the binary to the same folder as the script and changing the path to `var pathToFfmpeg = "ffmpeg.exe";`. It still worked locally, but not on Heroku even though the binary 100% should be there now. Running the chmod command returned code 0

Comment: I mean you definitely won't be able to run an .exe file like ffmpeg.exe on linux, you have to make sure you have a Linux binary on there that is build for the CPU architecture that Heroku uses.